# how to use brackets in javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, variables, input

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [use brackets in checkbox name when using php and javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207469/use-brackets-in-checkbox-name-when-using-php-and-javascript)

I use as name of input field in html code :

```
<input size="15" name="user[135][name]" value="" disabled=disabled>
```

then I want to work with it in javascript like this:

```
if(some_condition)  { document.myform.user[135][name].disabled=false; }
```

But that doesn't work, because of the brackets in field name. Is there any way how to solve it without changing html code?

Experience: if I use name as user_135_name all works perfectly.

thankx for help.

Maros

Comment: @PranavKapoor웃 — The value of the `name` attribute is a CDATA token not a NAME token. See [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-name-INPUT)

Comment: I studied Quentins possible duplicate thread, but as far as i could understand it (I'm not a master of javascript, i'm specialized in PHP) it is a little different and therefore not useful for me. or do you see something, that I do not?

Comment: @MarošMarkovič — That question is about using JS to access an input element which has `[` and `]` characters in the name. That is the same as your question.

Comment: yes, but he uses only one variable type[], then he can use f['type[]'][i]. how I can use it when I use other bracket user[135][name] ? maybe you see the solution, but I don't have an idea how to combine it :(

Comment: You put the name (the whole name, and nothing by the name) in the quotes. It doesn't matter how many `[]` are in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll suggest add `id` to your input tag as follows

```
<input size="15" id="user_name_135" name="user[135][name]" value="" disabled=disabled>
```

Using simple Javascript

```
if(some_condition) { document.getElementById("user_name_135").disabled=false; }
```

Using jQuery

```
if(some_condition){ $("#user_name_135").prop('disabled', false);}
```

Also if there is only one statement followed by `if` you can omit `{}`

```
if(some_condition) 
  document.getElementById("user_name_135").disabled=false;
```

Edited
Please save following code as a html file and see it should work for you

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function some(){
  document.getElementById("user_name_135").disabled=false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input size="15" id="user_name_135" name="user[135][name]" value="" disabled=disabled>
<a href ="javascript:void(0)" onclick="some()">disbale input</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: for complicated reasons I cannot use jquery, just some simple javascript. your idea doesn't work :( but thanx for try.

Comment: in that case just add `id="user_name_135"` to your input and then `if(some_condition) { document.getElementById("user_name_135").disabled=false; }`

Comment: Salil, I tried it, but it is not working :(

Comment: @Maroš Markovič :- see my edited answer it works for me and should work for you as well, may be your `condition` not get satisfied and hence input tag remain `disabled`

Comment: sounds promising. your example works fine, I implemented to larger scale in my form and still OK. last steps for full implementation will take me some time, so then I will be back with updates. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My only advice would be to not even try. Don't use 'special' characters in identifiers. If you need the identifier to be in a strict data format for the sake of some other thing, then apply that in a dedicated attribute (such as `data-xxx`, or something similar).

The solution is to use a different format, one that includes only alphanumeric and 'basic' characters (such as underscores instead of spaces, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

`document.myform['user[135][name]']` should work, but why do you have such strange names???

What you are tring in your code is to acces name property (if you have `['name']`) the 135th field in the array "user".

Comment: PHP will inflate them into a data structure of nested arrays when its default form handler library parses them.

Comment: So my answer is the same as in your linked question =) Didnt know that php is able to do that. Thank you!

Comment: exactly, I use it because when I send the form to PHP, it automatically makes the correct array without extra work :)

Comment: document.myform['user[135][name]'] doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Do not use special characters in names, you can do what you need like this:

```
if(some_condition)  { 
    document.getElementsByName('user[135][name]')[0].disabled=false; 
}
```

See live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Lw9ns/9/

Comment: Why doesn't this work? This is working for me.

Comment: See the jsFiddle for proof.